# Get Current User Logged on Time (CMD Batch)

Tags: windows-7, batch, cmd.exe, vbscript

OS: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1

Using the Windows command line, I can see the current user's logon time using the `quser` command. This results in more output than I desire, so I'm hoping to use `for` `skip` and `tokens` to get only the logon time and date.

As an example

```
c:\quser.exe
--------------------------
USERNAME         SESSIONNAME     ID    STATE      IDLE TIME      LOGON TIME
GenericUser      console         1     Active     1:22           03/11/2015 1:45 PM
```

Using `for`, I can whittle this down, but it's taking the space between the date and time as a delimiter and therefore only giving me the date:

```
c:\for /f "skip=1 tokens=6" %a in ('quser') do echo %a
--------------------------
03/11/2015
```

Note that the output is missing the "1:45 PM". Of note, I can't specify multiple tokens because there are only 6 headers, so I can't get a 7th token from the second line. How can I modify this to collect the time as well as the date?

*Don't worry about calculating the datediff, as I'll be handling that in VBScript once I can properly collect it.

Thanks in advance,
Beems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you **can** get 7th token from second line:
`for /f "skip=1 tokens=7" %a in ('quser') do @echo %a` produces `1:45`
but you may also use a `*` to get everything to the end of line:
`for /f "skip=1 tokens=5*" %a in ('quser') do @echo %b` produces: `03/11/2015 1:45 PM`
which I think is what you're after.

From `help for`:

> If
>   the last character in the tokens= string is an
>   asterisk, then an additional variable is
>   allocated and receives the remaining text on
>   the line after the last token parsed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the token with an asterisk per a link I found, but it looks like my big problem was I did `@echo %a` instead of `@echo %b`. do you know how to explain that difference to me? Thanks! Beems.

Comment: @Beems `for` variables are implicitly created by cmd, starting from first you specify, so in this case `%a` refers to token 5 (which is last token **before** what interests you)  and `%b` to rest of the line (minus any leading spaces)